# ¿Cómo evitar que el soft keyboard se muestre al pulsar una botón del teclado físico?

Tags: android-studio, android-softkeyboard

estoy realizando una aplicación para un dispositivo Android en Android Studio, necesito que el soft keyboard no se muestre cuando se está utilizando el teclado físico y darle al usuario la posibilidad de elegir si usar el teclado fisico o el virtual

Comment: Bienvenido @JAlfredoSantiago a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y de paso ganes tu primera medalla, también es muy importante que leas [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) para poder mejorar tus preguntas y que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad, favoreciendo tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Answer (score -1):

Es raro que un dispositivo tenga teclado fisico en estos dias. Pero podrias evitar que se muestre el softKeyboard con la siguiente linea de codigo:

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```

De igual manera podrias volver a habilitar el teclado para que se muestre usando

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE);
```